# Login with Twitter account in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to let users login with their twitter acount for my web site. I am using Tweetsharp library.

Now the problem is: after i enter twitter user name and password, the twitter page shows me a number like "7825362101" and says to enter this number into the concern web site.

I have no clue what shall my website do with that number!! I already have 'consumer key' and 'consumer secret' while i created the app in twitter.

I hope someone can help me!!
cheers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything with that number if you are using the Tweetsharp in a web application. Just do the following in your controller, this will return a list of tweets from the public timeline:

```
private readonly string _consumerKey = "yourconsumerkey";
private readonly string _consumerSecret = "yourconsumersecretkey";

public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);

            IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> model = service.ListTweetsOnPublicTimeline();

            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring.NET Twitter provides a sample for ASP.NET MVC.
http://www.springframework.net/social-twitter/

Answer (score 0):

I think something is missing on redirect to Twitter authentication.Twitter API not getting all required values. So just follow the below link to authenticate your web application using Tweetsharp library

http://tutorialslink.com/Articles/Login-with-Twitter-account-in-Aspnet-MVC/24